# Turf bbox taking in account rotation

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, turfjs

I have a set of polygons and I want to draw the smallest possible polygon around them (it has to be a rectangular shape, all inner angles 90 degrees).
To achieve this I used the `bboxPolygon` function from turf.js and it works okay, but it does not take in account rotation of the polygons.
For example take a look at the image bellow, the purple line is the `bboxPolygon` result but there is too much space at the sides, what I ultimately try to achieve is the corners should be near the topmost points of polygon `101` and bottom most of `202`. Is there some other method to use to achieve this? I tried `envelope` but I still get the same results...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a `bbox` is always aligned north/south/east/west.

In this particular case, a [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) is probably what you want. Turf supports that with the [convex](http://turfjs.org/docs/#convex) method.

Comment: This is very close to what I am looking for, but I need the end shape to be rectangular as well, only 4 points, and the convex method can have N number of points...

Comment: What you're asking for is not a standard function. You'll have to develop your own algorithm.